# Regex MatchCollection obj hangs\"Function evuluation timed out" after Regex.Matches

Tags: c#, .net

I'm kind of new too C#, and regular expression for that matter, but I've searched a couple of hours to find a solution too this problem so, hopefully this is easy for you guys:)

My application uses a regex to match email addresses in a given string,
then loops throu the matches.:

```
String EmailPattern = "\\w+([-+.]\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*";
MatchCollection mcemail = Regex.Matches(rawHTML, EmailPattern);

foreach (Match memail in mcemail)
```

Works fine, but, when I downloaded the string from a certain page, http://www.sp.se/sv/index/services/quality/sidor/default.aspx, the MatchCollection(mcemail) object "hangs" the loop. When using a break point and accessing the object, I get "Function evuluation timed out" on everything(.Count etc).

*Update*
I've tried my pattern and other email patterns on the same string, everyone(regex desingers, python based web pages etc.) fails/timesout when trying too match this particular string.

How can I detect that the matchcollection obj is not "ready" to use?

Comment: Here's a tip: if you prefix the string with @ you don't need double backslashes: `@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a local test and it appears either the sheer document size or something in the `ViewState` causes the Regex match evaluation to time out. (Edit: I'm pretty sure it's the size, actually. Removing the ViewState just reduces the size significantly.)

An admittedly crude way to solve this would be something like this:

```
string[] rawHtmlLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\default.aspx");
string filteredHtml = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    rawHtmlLines.Where(line => !line.Contains("_VIEWSTATE")).ToArray());
string emailPattern = @"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*";
var emailMatches = Regex.Matches(filteredHtml, emailPattern);

foreach (Match match in emailMatches)
{
    //...
}
```

Overall I suspect the email pattern is just not well optimised (or intended) to filter out emails in a large string but just used as validation for user input. Generally it might be a good idea to limit the string you search in to just the parts you are actually interested in and keep it as small as possible - for example by leaving out the `ViewState` which is guaranteed to not contain any readable email addresses.

If performance is important, it's probably also a better idea to create the filtered HTML using a `StringBuilder` and `IndexOf` (etc.) instead of splitting lines and LINQing up the result :)

Edit:

To further minimize the length of the string the Regex needs to check you could only include lines that contain the `@` character to begin with, like so:

```
string filteredHtml = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    rawHtmlLines.Where(line => line.IndexOf('@') >= 0 && !line.Contains("_VIEWSTATE")).ToArray());
```

Comment: Cheers, performence is not an that important, but will try your method too exclude "_VIEWSTATE" and such lines:)

Comment: @Johan Helsén: Please see my edit. I'm pretty sure the length of the string you are checking is the problem. I suspect your original code would also finish *eventually*, but because the pattern is very lenient it just has a lot of work to do in such a large string.

Comment: Thanks! This workes great. I tested your first solution too remove the _VIEMSTATE line and added RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace to the regex.matches(), and it worked fine:)

Answer (score 2):

If you can post the email that's causing the problem (perhaps anonymized in some way), that will give us more information, but I'm *thinking* the problem is this little guy right here:

```
([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*
```

To understand the problem, let's break that into groups:

```
([-.]\\w+)*
\\.\\w+
([-.]\\w+)*
```

The strings that will match `\\.\\w+` are a **subset** of those that will match `[-.]\\w+`. So if part of your input looks like `foo.bar.baz.blah.yadda.com`, your regex engine has no way of knowing which  group is supposed to match it. Does that make sense? So the first `([-.]\\w+)*` could match `.bar.baz.blah`, then the `\\.\\w+` could match `.yadda`, then the last `([-.]\\w+)*` could match `.com`...

...**OR** the first clause could match `.bar.baz`, the second could match `.blah`, and the last could match `.yadda.com`. Since it doesn't know which one is right, it will keep trying different combinations. It should stop eventually, but that could still take a long time. This is called "catastrophic backtracking".

This issue is compounded by the fact that you're using [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) rather than non-capturing groups; i.e. `([-+.]\\w+)` instead of `(?:[-+.]\\w+)`. That causes the engine to try and separate and save whatever matches inside the parentheses for later reference. But as I explained above, it's ambiguous which group each substring belongs in.

You might consider replacing everything after the @ with something like this:

```
\\w[-\\w]*\\.[-.\\w]+
```

That could use some refinement to make it more specific, but you get the general idea. Hope I explained all this well enough; grouping and backreferences are kind of tough to describe.

#### EDIT:

Looking back at your pattern, there's a deeper issue here, still related to the backtracking/ambiguity problem I mentioned. The clause `\\w+([-.]\\w+)*` is ambiguous all by itself. Splitting it into parts, we have:

```
\\w+
([-.]\\w+)*
```

Suppose you have a string like `foobar`. Where does the `\\w+` end and the `([-.]\\w+)*` begin? How many repetitions of `([-.]\\w+)` are there? Any of the following could work as matches:

```
f(oobar)
foo(bar)
f(o)(oba)(r)
f(o)(o)(b)(a)(r)
foobar
etc...
```

The regex engine doesn't know which is important, so it will try them all. This is the same problem I pointed out above, but it means you have it in multiple places in your pattern.

Even worse, `([-.]\\w+)*` is *also* ambiguous, because of the `+` after the `\\w`. How many groups are there in `blah`? I count 16 possible combinations: `(blah)`, `(b)(lah)`, `(bl)(ah)`...

The amount of different possible combinations is going to be huge, even for a relatively small input, so your engine is going to be in overdrive. I would definitely simplify it if I were you.

Comment: Thanks, will try too change that. Regarding which email causing the problem, I can't see that. The MatchCollection objects members isn't "acceessible". And I tried different patterns(see update in my post), and all seems to hang... "catastrophic backtracking":D

Comment: @Johan Helsén - Looking at the source code of that page, I see six email addresses. I suspect that if you tried *any* page with six email addresses in it, the program would hang because of the resource intensity of your regex. By the way, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. As you notice by viewing the regex I have, I have alot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

From "Function evaluation timed out", I'm assuming you're doing this in the debugger.  The debugger has some fairly quick timeouts with regard to how long a method takes.  Not eveything happens quickly.  I would suggest going the operation in code, storing the result, then viewing that result in the debugger (i.e. let the call to Matches run and put a breakpoint after it).

Now, with regard to detecting whether the string will make Matches take a long time; that's a bit of a black art.  You basically have to perform some sort of input validation.  Just because you got some value from the internet, doesn't mean that value will work well with Matches.  The ultimate validation logic is up to you; but, starting with the length of rawHtmlLines might be useful. (i.e. if the lenght is 1000000 bytes, Matches might take a while)  But, you have to decide what to do if the length is too long; e.g give an error to the user.

Comment: Thx, will try too break big strings into smaller and match them instead.